Pipenv install fails due to deprecated package
I've got a python package with the following Pipfile:
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
boto3 = "*"
s3urls = "*"
tabulate = "*"
surfaceutils = {editable = true, git = "ssh://git.amazon.com/pkg/MiddleMileSurfaceResearchUtils"}
s3fs = "<0.5.0"
importlib-metadata = "*"
pandas = "*"
isodate = "*"
sklearn = "*"
numpy = "*"
timedelta = "*"
django-timedeltafield = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"

When I try running pipenv install from within this package I get the following error:
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /local/home/kinable/workspace/amazon/Cobra-Benchmarking/Pipfile
Using /local/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/bin/python3.9 (3.9.19) to create virtualenv...
⠸ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.9.19.final.0-64 in 201ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/local/home/kinable/.local/share/virtualenvs/Cobra-Benchmarking-mtu2zcpw, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/local/home/kinable/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==24.0, setuptools==69.2.0, surfaceutils==2021.9.0, wheel==0.43.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /home/kinable/.local/share/virtualenvs/Cobra-Benchmarking-mtu2zcpw
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (999ffc)...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting boto3==1.26.98 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 1))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached boto3-1.26.98-py3-none-any.whl (135 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting botocore==1.29.98 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 2))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached botocore-1.29.98-py3-none-any.whl (10.5 MB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting django-timedeltafield==0.7.10 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 3))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached django-timedeltafield-0.7.10.tar.gz (13 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting fsspec==2023.3.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 4))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached fsspec-2023.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting importlib-metadata==6.1.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 5))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached importlib_metadata-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting isodate==0.6.1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 6))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached isodate-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting jmespath==1.0.1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 7))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached jmespath-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting numpy==1.24.2 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 8))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached numpy-1.24.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.3 MB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting pandas==1.5.3 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 9))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached pandas-1.5.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.2 MB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.2 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 10))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting pytz==2022.7.1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 11))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached pytz-2022.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (499 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting s3fs==0.4.2 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 12))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached s3fs-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting s3transfer==0.6.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 13))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached s3transfer-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting s3urls==0.0.3 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 14))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached s3urls-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.5 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting six==1.16.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 15))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting sklearn==0.0.post1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-eiti58sv-requirements/pipenv-exmlxe5_-hashed-reqs.txt (line 16))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached sklearn-0.0.post1.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   │ exit code: 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ╰─> [18 lines of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       The 'sklearn' PyPI package is deprecated, use 'scikit-learn'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       rather than 'sklearn' for pip commands.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       Here is how to fix this error in the main use cases:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       - use 'pip install scikit-learn' rather than 'pip install sklearn'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       - replace 'sklearn' by 'scikit-learn' in your pip requirements files
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         (requirements.txt, setup.py, setup.cfg, Pipfile, etc ...)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       - if the 'sklearn' package is used by one of your dependencies,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         it would be great if you take some time to track which package uses
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         'sklearn' instead of 'scikit-learn' and report it to their issue tracker
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       - as a last resort, set the environment variable
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         SKLEARN_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_SKLEARN_PACKAGE_INSTALL=True to avoid this error
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       More information is available at
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       https://github.com/scikit-learn/sklearn-pypi-package
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       If the previous advice does not cover your use case, feel free to report it at
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       https://github.com/scikit-learn/sklearn-pypi-package/issues/new
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: error: metadata-generation-failed
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: 
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ╰─> See above for output.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: 
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: hint: See above for details.
ERROR: Couldn't install package: {}
 Package installation failed...
/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:1052: ResourceWarning: subprocess 33373 is still running
  _warn("subprocess %s is still running" % self.pid,
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=4 encoding='utf-8'>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=7 encoding='utf-8'>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

According to the error message, I need to replace sklearn by scikit-learn in the Pipfile. I tried to accomplish that by running: pipenv install scikit-learn. This however produces the following error:
Installing scikit-learn...
Resolving scikit-learn...
Added scikit-learn to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (999ffc) out of date, updating to (9ef4a3)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠸ Locking...False
INFO:pip.subprocessor:Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet ssh://git.amazon.com/pkg/MiddleMileSurfaceResearchUtils /tmp/pip-temp-fl2magyw/surfaceutils_d012b7bb121447ddbeccd9fe702be520
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 645, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 612, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 592, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 918, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, internal_resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 691, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 448, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: metadata generation failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 209, in install
    do_install(
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 297, in do_install
    raise e
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 281, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 648, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/routines/lock.py", line 65, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 859, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
  File "/home/kinable/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 728, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!

I'm not quite sure how to proceed?

You may have incompatible sub-dependencies perhaps ? Try installing just scikit-learn in a brand new (empty) venv. Then add the other dependencies one by one (boto, s3urls, ...).

try to use poetry - it might resolve dependencies
